# How to avoid "Navigating away" error on IE when using href links

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:popup('example.htm')">example</a>


<SCRIPT>
function popup(URL)
{
popup=window.open(.....);
popup.focus;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

On IE when I click the link, I get the "Navigating away..." error before opening the pop-up window. How can I fix to code to get to the pop-up directly without using JQuery?

I found

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

but where should I insert it in my code?

Comment: If you allow IE to navigate away, where does it navigate to?

Comment: it still opens the popup window (which is the desired outcome) but I don't want the error message to appear first

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Can go anywhere you want in your code. Also using a return value of `false` in the popup function will probably correct the problem.

Good luck!